# Initializing a getter in python after converting to string

Tags: python

I need these two getters to return the string converted version of the x input or y input. 
Please take a look at my code, and let me know where I faulter. Thanks!

```
class V:
    def __init__(self, conv, convy):
        conv = conv
        convy = convy

        self.conv = str(conv)
        self.convy = str(convy)

    def getX(self):
        return self.__conv

    def getY(self):
        return self.__convy
```

Comment: What are those double-underscore prefixes for? `self.conv` is not the same as `self.__conv`.

Comment: Why do you use `conv = conv` and `convy = convy`?

Comment: Please read ["What is the meaning of a single- and a double-underscore before an object name?"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1301346/416224) if you wonder why you can't access `v.__self` (at least with that name) outside of the class body.

Answer (score 1):

Your getter is defined as:

```
def getX(self):
    return self.__conv
```

But `self.__conv` does not exist. Instead, you defined `self.conv`.

Therefore, your getter should be:

```
def getX(self):
    return self.conv
```

In addtion, in your `__init__` method, you assign `conv` and `convy` to themselves, which is absolutely useless:

```
def __init__(self, conv, convy):
    conv = conv
    convy = convy
```

You should get rid of these two lines that serve no purpose.